# Assigning categorical values to NAs randomly or proportionally

Tags: r, na

I have a dataset:

```
df <- structure(list(gender = c("female", "male", NA, NA, "male", "male", 
"male"), Division = c("South Atlantic", "East North Central", 
"Pacific", "East North Central", "South Atlantic", "South Atlantic", 
"Pacific"), Median = c(57036.6262, 39917, 94060.208, 89822.1538, 
107683.9118, 56149.3217, 46237.265), first_name = c("Marilyn", 
"Jeffery", "Yashvir", "Deyou", "John", "Jose", "Daniel")), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I need to perform an analysis such that I can't have `NA` values in the `gender` variable.  The other columns are too few and have no known predictive value so that imputing the values isn't really possible.

I can perform the analysis by removing the incomplete observations entirely - they are about 4% of the dataset, but I'd like to see the results by randomly assigning `female` or `male` into the missing cases.

Other than writing some pretty ugly code to filter to just incomplete cases, split in two and replace `NA`s with `female` or `male` in each half, I wondered if there was an elegant way to randomly or proportionally assign values into `NA`s?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `ifelse` and `is.na` to determine if `na` exist, and then use `sample` to randomly select `female` and `male`.

```
df$gender <- ifelse(is.na(df$gender), sample(c("female", "male"), 1), df$gender)
```

Comment: It is from base R.

Comment: works just fine with the base or `dplyr::sample` thanks.

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
> df <- structure(list(gender = c("female", "male", NA, NA, "male", "male", 
+                                 "male"),
+                      Division = c("South Atlantic", "East North Central", 
+                                   "Pacific", "East North Central", "South Atlantic", "South Atlantic", 
+                                   "Pacific"),
+                      Median = c(57036.6262, 39917, 94060.208, 89822.1538,
+                                 107683.9118, 56149.3217, 46237.265),
+                      first_name = c("Marilyn", "Jeffery", "Yashvir", "Deyou", "John", "Jose", "Daniel")),
+                 row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
> 
> Gender <- rbinom(length(df$gender), 1, 0.52)
> Gender <- factor(Gender, labels = c("female", "male"))
> 
> df$gender[is.na(df$gender)] <- as.character(Gender[is.na(df$gender)])
> 
> df$gender
[1] "female" "male"   "female" "female" "male"   "male"   "male"  
>
```

Thats is random with a given probability. You could also consider imputing values using nearest neighbors, hot desk, or similar.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Just assign

```
df$gender[is.na(df$gender)]=sample(c("female", "male"), dim(df)[1], replace = TRUE)[is.na(df$gender)]
```